# ViewWillDisappear nil values for navigation/tab controller

Tags: ios, swift

I need to reconfigure the size of the `UINavigationController` inside my `UITabController`. This works fine when the view loads, in `viewWillAppear()`. However, when I try to resize in `viewWillDisappear`, I get nil values for both the Nav/Tab controller. Example:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false //po self.navigationController --> nil
    ...
    var smallerFrame: CGRect = (self.tabBarController?.view.frame)!; //po self.tabBarController --> nil
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure what's going on. Why would this happen in `viewWillDisappear` but not `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: You can alternatively try `self.presentingViewController?`

Comment: What happens if you move super.viewWillDisappear to the end of the method ?

Comment: @CraigOtis I still get nil.

Comment: how are you showing this VC ?

Comment: Through a navigation controller. The view is being presented with a push and removed with a pop.

Comment: could you post that code where you do push and pop ?  It might help to understand situation clearly.

Comment: I had the same problem. Ended up setting a weak property to navigation controller in viewDidLoad. @property(weak, nonatomic) UINavigationController *weakNavigationController;

Comment: @almas that's it! If you want to write it as an answer, i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem. Ended up setting a weak property to navigation controller in viewDidLoad.

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) UINavigationController *weakNavigationController;
```